# Appium server throwing Unhandled error: Error: connect ECONNREFUSED

Tags: appium, android-uiautomator, econnrefused

I'm using appium 1.4. Just before client connection to appium server, an appium server socket is created on port 4274. But when client is trying to connect it gets the following exception:

> 2015-06-03 08:52:32:541 - info: [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Socket opened on port 4724
>   2015-06-03 08:52:32:554 - info: [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Appium Socket Server Ready
>   2015-06-03 08:52:32:555 - info: [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Loading json...
>   2015-06-03 08:52:32:555 - info: [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Registered crash watchers.
>   2015-06-03 08:52:33:552 - error: Unhandled error: Error: connect ECONNREFUSED
>       at errnoException (net.js:904:11)
>       at Object.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:895:19) context: [POST /wd/hub/session {"desiredCapabilities":{"automationName":"Appium","platformVersion":"Nokia X software platform 1.1","deviceName":"Nokia XL Dual SIM","platformName":"Android","browserName":"Browser"}}]

But, there is no server socket created on port 4274 on host where appium is running.

Could someone suggest me what went wrong and how to resolve this issue ?